# Batch vs Command Line Plink Output to File

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I'm able to run the below command using the command line, but not in a batch file.

```
plink -ssh -pw password -batch root@ip "ping -w 1 -c 1 server | grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)' > test.txt"
```

The resulting txt file's contents when ran from the command line is "0", indicating no packet loss. The resulting txt file when ran from a batch file is empty. Possibly a character escape issue in the batch file?

Comment: I don't have plink available, but try either changing `|` to `^|` or `%` to `%%`. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not confident enough that that's the cause, but those two things usually break things when going from the command prompt to a batch script.

Comment: I doubt the `|` is an issue, but @SomethingDark is correct about the `%` which needs to be doubled. _Are you sure that the `> test.txt` shouldn't be outside of the closing doublequote?_

Comment: Extra % was the answer, thanks. "Are you sure that the > test.txt shouldn't be outside of the closing doublequote?" That depends on where you want the text file located. Inside the quotes will place it on the server, outside will be local.